# WPF Image won't show in Class Library Project

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I can't display an image on WPF window during runtime. However, it is shown during design mode. The image is located in Images folder and Build action is set to Content as well is Copy to output to Copy Always. The output  Any suggestions?

===EDIT====

The output type of a project is : Class Libray, if I change it to Window Application the bellow are workign fine. However I still need to build it is Class library.

2nd try

```
<Image Source="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/Images/Logo2.png" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

3rd try

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Images/Logo2.png" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Also,
If I put a full path to the image location it is working, apparently this is not ideal situation:

```
<Image Source="C:/.../Images/Logo2.png" Grid.Row="0"/>
```

Comment: `siteoforigin` should work. Cross check in output folder that you have images located there.

Comment: Well, actually I did check, image is there but still not showing it

Comment: It works fine for me in small app. Second option.

Comment: You probably right... but it seems in my solution it refuses to do so, plus I am not sure how to debug it

Answer (score 3):

**Rebuild** your entire solution and try again. It probably didn't do a build with images in it when you tried it again.

Also use your 3rd try again then build action to **content**, no need to make a copy always.

Comment: I've edited a question ... it seems full path is working

Comment: @Jim Full path is working because you copy the images, where as using pack where it is tied to the binaries. That's why I said change build action to resource. Unless you want to expose the images in your output directory.

Comment: I tried the 3rd solution byt settin BuildAction : Resources and All copy to output options... But image is not showing

Comment: @Jim Did you rebuild? Not build

Comment: Yes... Rebuild, Totally clean the solution etc

Comment: @Jim My bad, change build action to content.

Comment: I've edited thte question it has to do something with Output type of the project.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this more.. I thought I knew WPF (been doing it since it came out) then I tried to upgrade a .NET 2 class library to 3.5 and replace some forms with WPF and new PNG images.. Tried Content and Resource, etc. Was only getting errors no matter what pack URI I tried.. Then found this and clean-rebuild did the trick. Feel like an idiot for not trying it sooner. Saved me from possible insanity..

Answer (score 0):

After several trials the answer was quite simple:

For Class Library Project set your images Build Action to Resource and get a reference in Xaml as:

```
<Image Source="/YOURNAMESPACE;component/Images/Logo.png"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work with png, but convert to jpg and write:

```
<Image Source="/YOURNAMESPACE;component/Images/Logo.jpg"/>
```

That works for me :)